# Open Settings from iOS app (deep stuff)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, settings

As you may have heard Apple "killed" Settings.app URL scheme in iOS 5.1 Beta, which became public to everyone last month.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=..."]]` no longer works. 
Maybe they use something instead of "openURL" or what?

I have also heard that there is some private API, which is used for Enterprise development (but it's deleted from devforums), is it the same as everyone using or different?

Is there other private API which can open Settings.app?

Comment: iOS 5.1 is beta and  under NDA, and didnt become public to everyone, but only the devs..

Comment: I'm only interested in different way/private api to open Settings.app, I don't cover any 5.1 features, except it's number.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com)?

Comment: He's not asking about application settings, but how to access the system settings panel.